# CodeIgniter - Sending content to controller via ajax and through code igniter email library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I have an application where i have a wysiwyg editor to design emails and send them to contacts in a database, i have the email function working as when i test with an input form it sends to my database contacts, however i am trying to pass the content in the wysiwyg editor through ajax to my controller but when the emails are received they show up with the word 'false'..

My Controller

```
public function sendmail() {


$this->load->library('email');
$this->load->model('Email_model');
$this->load->library('session');
$this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input-
>post('name'));
$this->email->to($this->Email_model->emailsend());
$this->email->subject('Hello This is an email');
$this->email->message($this->input->post('content'));

if ($this->email->send()){

   $this->load->view('header');
  $this->load->view('sentConfirm');
  $this->load->view('footer');

}else{
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
}
```

My Ajax

```
$('#sendEmail').click(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?=site_url("dashboard/sendmail"); ?>",
    data: {
    content: $("trumbowyg-demo").trumbowyg('html')
},
    dataType: 'json',
success: function(response){
console.log('Sent Successfully');
}
});
});
```

Comment: you need to add $mail->IsHTML(true); before $mail->message because the content from wysiwyg editor returns is html

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya this returns Call to undefined method CI_Email::IsHTML()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax

```
$('#sendEmail').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?=site_url("dashboard/sendmail"); ?>",
        data: {content: $("trumbowyg-demo").trumbowyg('html')},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.ok==1) {
                alert('sent');
            }else{
                alert('failed');
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

your controller

```
public function sendmail() {
        $configs = Array(
          'mailtype' => 'html'
          //see other config in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences
        );

        $this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($configs);
        $this->load->model('Email_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));
        $this->email->to($this->Email_model->emailsend());
        $this->email->subject('Hello This is an email');
        $this->email->message($this->input->post('content'));

        $result['ok'] = 0;
        if ($this->email->send()){
            $result["ok"]=1;
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We recommend phpmailer instead of codeigniter email assistant.

Try it ;
https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer